# MySQL drop scheduled event syntax ERROR 1064 (42000)

Tags: mysql, server, scheduled-tasks, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to drop a scheduled event but keep getting this error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[IF EXISTS] some_event' at line 1

This is what I'm typing into the terminal: `DROP EVENT [IF EXISTS] some_event;`

I am doing this on Ubuntu Server 14.04. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: remove square brackets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `[]` brackets are used only to indicate that this part is optional in documentation:

```
DROP EVENT IF EXISTS some_event;
```

**[`Typographical and Syntax Conventions`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/manual-conventions.html)**:

> In syntax descriptions, **square brackets** (“[” and “]”) indicate
>   optional words or clauses. For example, in the following statement, IF
>   EXISTS is optional:
>
> DROP TABLE [IF EXISTS] tbl_name

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know brackets meant optional.